# Terminal Linux Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

How can I move a directory into another directory via ubuntu terminal?

I found a forum that said to do as in this example mv teste1 / test2 (in the case of tests are folders) but when I do that it renames it so I tried mv / teste1 / test2 but it gives an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: in Linux/UNIX you should escape space symbol if it's part of path or filename. And the command is like:

```
mv test1 test2
```

(this will move directory `test1` inside `test2`)